# Validation errors in AJAX mode

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Currently I use this to display validation errors via ajax:

```
            if (data.validation_failed == 1)
            {
                var arr = data.errors;
                $.each(arr, function(index, value)
                {
                    if (value.length != 0)
                    {
                        $("#validation-errors").append('<div class="alert alert-error"><strong>'+ value +'</strong><div>');
                    }
                });
                $('#ajax-loading').hide();
                $("#validation-errors").show();
            }
```

It works fine, does exactly what I need.

The problem is what I have to do to transport the errors from laravel to ajax:

```
    $rules = array( 
        'name'  => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    );

    $v = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ( ! $v->passes())
    {

    $messages = $v->messages();

    foreach ($rules as $key => $value)
    {
        $verrors[$key] = $messages->first($key);
    }

        if(Request::ajax())
        {                    
            $response_values = array(
                'validation_failed' => 1,
                'errors' => $verrors);              
        return Response::json($response_values);
        }
        else
        {
        return Redirect::to('login')
            ->with('validation_failed', 1)
            ->withErrors($v);
        }       

    }
```

If I want to have the field names as key, I have to iterate $rules, but even if I don't use field names as key, yet I have to iterate error messages to construct $verrors.

How could I convert `$v->messages()` to the equivalent of `$verrors` without the need to iterate? Since `Response::json()` is expecting an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The easiest way is to leverage the `MessageBag` object of the validator. This can be done like this:

```
// Setup the validator
$rules = array('username' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required');
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

// Validate the input and return correct response
if ($validator->fails())
{
    return Response::json(array(
        'success' => false,
        'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()

    ), 400); // 400 being the HTTP code for an invalid request.
}
return Response::json(array('success' => true), 200);
```

This would give you a JSON response like this:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "errors": {
        "username": [
            "The username field is required."
        ],
        "password": [
            "The password field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be a stupid comment - but doesn't setting the http code to 400 mean the JSON response is completely ignored?

Comment: Depends on the 'client' reading the JSON. jQuery for example handles this perfectly fine. It doesn't trigger the success, but the error callback, which is what you want.

Comment: Using jQuery, you can get errors using this code in the ajax request: `error: function(xhr, status, data){
                    console.log(xhr.responseJSON.errors);
                  }`

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to modify the response to return one string per field instead of an array? I was trying to get several error strings in one field, but it seems not possible.

Comment: @JCarlos The message bag groups them in an array. You could map over the items like this: `'errors' => array_map(function($fieldErrors) { return $fieldErrors[0]; }, $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray())`

Comment: I was trying to generate a JSON response with just one string per field from Laravel, because next I have to parse it in Android.

Comment: Wow, great, just what I needed!

Answer (score 19):

In the ajax response trying something like

```
    .fail(function( data ) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
        var errorString = '<ul>';
        $.each( response.errors, function( key, value) {
            errorString += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
        });
        errorString += '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 14):

**Laravel 5 returns validation error automatically**

for that you just need to do following thing,

## Controller:

```
public function methodName(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'field-to-validate' => 'required'
    ]);

    // if it's correctly validated then do the stuff here

    return new JsonResponse(['data'=>$youCanPassAnything],200);
}
```

## View:

```
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'url-to-call',
            data: {
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                "field": $('#field').cal()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (reject) {
                if( reject.status === 422 ) {
                    var errors = $.parseJSON(reject.responseText);
                    $.each(errors, function (key, val) {
                        $("#" + key + "_error").text(val[0]);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

you can build for each `validation` field one `<span>` tag with id as field name and suffix `_error` so it will show validation error with above logic like as follow,

```
<span id="field_error"></span>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: but if for example i correct one error and click again, how i can remove that specific message that was an error and now is corrected?

Comment: @MarcoBozzola you need to remove all message and set messages from response again if it's failing, otherwise all good.

Comment: good example bro

Answer (score 8):

Try this code. It works well:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
});



$("#sendData").submit(function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData  = new FormData(jQuery('#sendData')[0]);
    $.ajax({

       type:'POST',
       url:"/your(URL)",
       data:formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
       success:function(data)
       {
          alert(data);
       },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) 
        {

          $.each(xhr.responseJSON.errors, function (key, item) 
          {
            $("#errors").append("<li class='alert alert-danger'>"+item+"</li>")
          });

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 5):

I handled it using this way for laravel 5.5

Html code

```
<div class="form-group  padding">
  <label for="">Kalyan Mandap Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Kalyan Mandap Name" id="mandapName" name="mandapName" value = "<?php echo (isset($mandapDetails['vchKalyanMandapName'])) ? $mandapDetails['vchKalyanMandapName'] : ""; ?>" required="required">
  <span class="text-danger">{!! $errors->first('mandapName', ':message') !!} </span>
</div>
```

Controller validation code

```
 // Validate form data
    $validatedData = request()->validate([
      'mandapName' => 'required',
      'location' => 'required',
      'landmark' => 'required',
      'description' => 'required',
      'contactNo' => 'required',
      'slug' => 'required',
      'functional' => 'required'
    ]);
```

And in javascript

```
     $.ajax({
        //.....Your ajax configuration
        success: function (data) {
            // Success code

        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            $('[name="mandapName"]').next('span').html(request.responseJSON.errors.mandapName);
            //.......
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a better way to handle validation errors when using Ajax request.

Create a Request class as usual, for example `UploadFileAjaxRequest`:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'file' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Use it in a controller method:

```
public function uploadFileAjax(UploadFileAjaxRequest $request)
```

If there is any error, it will return an array of errors which you can use in JS:

```
$.ajax({
    ....
    error: function(data) {
        var errors = data.responseJSON; // An array with all errors.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I made it, try this hope it will help you with rendering errors after the relevant fields.

```
$("#booking_form").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                let form_data = $("#booking_form").serialize()
                $(document).find("span.text-danger").remove();
                $.ajax({
                    url : "your-url",
                    type : "POST",
                    data : form_data,
                    success : function(response){

                    },
                    error:function (response){
                        $.each(response.responseJSON.errors,function(field_name,error){
                            $(document).find('[name='+field_name+']').after('<span class="text-strong text-danger">' +error+ '</span>')
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
```

Answer (score 2):

As usual, we add validation without ajax do as it

```
public function genreAdd(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|name|unique:genre'
        ]);
    
        // If the code reaches this point, it means the validation passed.
        // Perform any necessary actions and return a response.
        return response()->json($request->all());
    }
```

This way you can show error validation using ajax as same as without ajax

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'genre-add',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                        'name': genre_name,
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        var errors = jqXHR.responseJSON.errors;
                        for (var fieldName in errors) {
                            if (errors.hasOwnProperty(fieldName)) {
                                var errorMessages = errors[fieldName];

                                errorMessages.forEach(function(errorMessage) {
                                    console.log(errorMessage);
                                    NioApp.Toast(errorMessage, 'error', {position: 'top-right'});
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }



                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Laravel 5.1 by the way but i think the fundamentals of this should apply to other versions. Laravel sends back the validation error response automatically.
You can just do the following in your controller:

```
public function processEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email'
    ]);
    return response()->json(['message'=>'success']);
}
```

Then in your javascript (i'm using jQuery here):

```
var params = {email: 'get-from-form-input@test.com'};
$.ajax({
    url: '/test/example',
    method: 'POST',
    data: params
})
.done(function( data ) {
    // do something nice, the response was successful
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    var responseMsg = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
    var errorMsg = 'There was a general problem with your request';
    if (responseMsg.hasOwnProperty('email')) {
        errorMsg = responseMsg.email;
        console.log(errorMsg);
    }
    // This will help you debug the response
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
});
```

If you look at the output on the console you'll soon see how to grab anything you want from the response sent back by Laravel. In that response the error messages are in json as key-value pairs where the key is the name of the field that failed validation, in my example 'email'.
Remember to ensure the ajax route is set up in your routes.php file and the method (get/post) matches that in the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I want to share what worked for me:

In backend I did something similar as the first answer in this post points out:

(In "$arrayValidate" I validate with Regular Expressions, if you don't know how they work, just text me and I will be glad to explain)

```
    public function createUser(Request $request){
        
    $arrayRequest = [
        "name" => $request->name,
        "document" => $request->document,
        "password" => $request->password
    ];

    $arrayValidate = [
        "name" => ["required",'regex:/^[a-zñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/i'],
        "document" => ["required",'regex:/^\d{6,12}$/', 'unique:tb_usuarios'],
        "password" => ["required",'regex:/^.{8,}$/']
    ];

    $response = Validator::make($arrayRequest, $arrayValidate);

    if($response->fails()){
        return Response::json([
            'response' => false,
            'errors' => $response->getMessageBag()->toArray()
        ], 422);
    }

    $response = User::create([
        "name" => $request->name,
        "document" => $request->document,
        "password" => Hash::make($request->password)
    ]);

    return Response::json(['success' => true], 200);
    }
```

In frontend with Javascript, we obtain the response of the validation ready to handle:

```
    axios({
        url: `create`,
        method: 'post',
        responseType: 'json',
        data: datos // Your data here
    })
    .then((res) => {
        if(res.status==200) {
            return res.data
        }
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Here we obtain an object of arrays with the response of the validation, which fields are correct and which ones are incorrect
        console.log(error.response.data.errors)            
    })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)    
    })
```