# View is rendered on Redirect::to but not displaying after POST and form validation

Tags: angularjs, post, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I have the following method submitting a form from an angular controller:

```
$scope.register = function() {
        var player = {
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password,
            username: $scope.username,
            name: $scope.playername
        }

        $http.post('register', player);
}
```

This works fine, the following route handles this http request (server side Routes.php):

```
Route::post('register', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doRegister'));
```

I then have the following code in my doRegister() method. The idea is to validate the form input before pushing to the database. Problem is, none of the two redirects work:

```
public function doRegister(){
        //Creates validator 
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $player);
        //In case it fails, redirect to the same form. But it doesn't work
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::except('password'));      
        } else {
            //Creates new user and writes to database. Redirect doesn't work either...
            return Redirect::to('lobby')->withSuccess('Registered!');
        }
}
```

What's really odd about this is that it *does* render the views. After clicking submit:
[image: Laravel debugbar after submitting valid form values]

Any idea why this happens? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Redirects don't work with ajax calls

Comment: So, I need to handle a promise in the angular controller? But then how do I take advantage of laravel's validation? I'm an absolute begginer before anything

Comment: Exactly. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17098374/1903366) shows how to use validation

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a last quick question: basically in my angular promise is where I have to handle the ajax response from laravel and change my views (eg. with document.location.replace)?

Comment: Yes. (Or use the angular router but that doesn't really make a difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To sum up the comments:*

Conventional redirects don't work when using ajax. Normally the browser would get a `302` response and then redirect accordingly, however angulars $http.post will do nothing. You have to take care of that yourself.

Regarding validation and error messages, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17098374/1903366) show's how you can send them back using JSON.

Here's a simple example taken from the answer linked above:

```
if ($validator->fails()){
    return Response::json(array(
        'success' => false,
        'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
    ), 400);
}
```